# Problema em ativar o ambiente virtual com pipenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, ambiente

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao abrir o powershell dentro do Visual  Studio Code, primeiro,  apareceu o erro de que a execução de scripts havia sido desabilitada, fui no powershell do windows e mudei a política de execução. Pois agora aparece o seguinte impasse: "You must 'source' this script: PS > .&"

Tentei pesquisar em outras fontes um tutorial de como "Sourcing a Script" mas não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Para ativar a virtualenv em um projeto usando o PipEnv basta entrar na pasta onde tem o arquivo `PipFile` e usar o comando `pipenv shell`.

Comment: To fazendo um curso, e esse foi uma das etapas para ativa-lo seguir exatamente como o autor mandou, no entanto, houve um erro de política de execução de scripts, me deparei que deveria mudar a política de execução dos scripts, fui lá mudei, e agora estou nesse impasse.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

O caminho desse ambiente virtual no seu projeto está muito estranho.
*C:\Users\julia.virtualenvs\Projeto_webscrap-ezhEVcLU\Scripts\activate.ps1*
o .virtualenvs seria a pasta do sei ambiente virtual.

O ideal é você recriar seu ambiente novamente.

1. Delete a pasta do ambiente virtual.
2. Abra o CMD na pasta raiz do projeto.
3. Execute os comandos abaixo para criar e ativar o ambiente.

> python -m pip install virtualenv
>
> python -m venv venv
>
> pip install --upgrade pip
>
> .\venv\scripts\activate

Depois instale suas dependências já dentro do ambiente virtual.

> pip install -r requirements.txt

Sobre a política de execução do Windows rode o comando abaixo no powershell  como admin.

> Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned

Answer (score -1):

Olá, na linha de comando tem um & na frente do comando. É necessário isso ?

Da uma olhada nesse link: https://jtemporal.com/venv-inicio/ pode te ajudar um pouco.

Comment: Eu tirei esse "&", e dessa vez aparece 

"You must 'source' this script: PS> . C:\Users\julia\.virtualenvs\Projeto_webscrap-ezhEVcLU\Scripts\activate.ps1"

Answer (score -2):

Abra o Powershell como Administrador e execute o seguinte comando:

Set-ExecutionPolicy -Executionpolicy AllSigned

Em seguida selecione 'A'. Isso vai "autorizar" a execução. Depois talvez vai perguntar novamente no terminal, quando executar o Activate.